# Posting local image file using graph API

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm hoping to POST to the graph API's /[event_id]/photos endpoint to allow a user to upload to one of their events. The documentation makes it seem like it is possible to upload a local file attachment instead of specifying a url of an image already on the internet.

I'm using the react-native-fbsdk library, but I can't figure out how to upload the photo. Here is what I have right now:

```
sharePhotoToEvent: (eventId, imageUrl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const eventsRequest = new GraphRequest(
            `/${eventId}/photos`,
            {
                httpMethod: 'POST',
                parameters: {
                    url: imageUrl
                }
            },
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Event photo upload error:');
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                } else if (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    resolve(result);
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
        );
        // Start the graph request.
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(eventsRequest).start();
    });
}
```

The imageUrl is the file path to the local image saved on device. Do I need to use a different undocumented parameter than "url"? Is there some other step that I need to do other than just providing the local file path?

The local file path is of the form:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D3394FBD8-91E3-48B0-E32E-A1KDN831349E/Documents/mimi_image.jpg

Here is the error response I am getting:

```
{ domain: 'com.facebook.sdk.core',
message: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)',
userInfo: 
 { NSRecoveryAttempter: null,
   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion: 'The server is temporarily busy, please try again.',
   'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey': 
    { code: 500,
      body: 
       { error: 
          { type: 'OAuthException',
            message: 'An unknown error has occurred.',
            fbtrace_id: 'DE2PvnZlqm8',
            code: 1 } } },
   'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey': 'An unknown error has occurred.',
   'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey': 500,
   'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode': 1,
   'com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey': 1,
   NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions: [ 'OK' ] },
nativeStackIOS: 
 [ '0   mimi                                0x0000000100dd6148 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 152',
   '1   mimi                                0x0000000100dd6070 RCTJSErrorFromNSError + 264',
   '2   mimi                                0x00000001010c8590 __48-[RCTFBSDKGraphRequestConnectionContainer start]_block_invoke + 156',
   '3   mimi                                0x0000000100b35c2c -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 152',
   '4   mimi                                0x0000000100b3ca9c __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke + 160',
   '5   mimi                                0x0000000100b3c8e8 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] + 956',
   '6   mimi                                0x0000000100b3e568 __76-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processorDidAttemptRecovery:didRecover:error:]_block_invoke + 64',
   '7   mimi                                0x0000000100b35c2c -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 152',
   '8   mimi                                0x0000000100b3ca9c __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke + 160',
   '9   mimi                                0x0000000100b3c8e8 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] + 956',
   '10  mimi                                0x0000000100b3c388 __64-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:]_block_invoke + 400',
   '11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181f9b988 <redacted> + 216',
   '12  mimi                                0x0000000100b3c124 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:] + 556',
   '13  mimi                                0x0000000100b3b4f0 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeFBSDKURLSessionWithResponse:data:networkError:] + 1012',
   '14  mimi                                0x0000000100b39638 __36-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection start]_block_invoke_2 + 80',
   '15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103b6d49c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24',
   '16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103b6d45c _dispatch_client_callout + 16',
   '17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103b72050 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1192',
   '18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182069eb0 <redacted> + 12',
   '19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182067a8c <redacted> + 2012',
   '20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181f87fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436',
   '21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000183e1ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100',
   '22  UIKit                               0x000000018b55c2e8 UIApplicationMain + 208',
   '23  mimi                                0x0000000100a5d3e4 main + 124',
   '24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000181aaa56c <redacted> + 4' ],
code: 'ECOM.FACEBOOK.SDK.CORE8' }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I just added the error code. Sorry for the delay, but perhaps you may still have some guidance.